# MYSQL : Get data from multiple table using JOIN and UNION in single row

Tags: mysql, database, join, union, calculation

**I have three database tables ‘customer’, ‘billing’, and ‘transaction’**

**customer:**

| cuid | name | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David | City 1 |
| 2 | Roja | City 2 |

**billing :**

| id | cuid | month | bill_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 400 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | 100 |

**transaction:**

| id | cuid | date | received_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-3-02 | 250 |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-2-02 | 200 |
| 3 | 2 | 2022-3-02 | 200 |

**I need a new generated Due table after calculating month wise due amount using FIFO like this:**

| cuid | Name | Address | Month | Due_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David | City 1 | 2 | 50 |
| 1 | David | City 1 | 3 | 100 |

**This code did not work properly. MySql Code:**

```
SELECT 
    due.cuid,
    due.Name,
    due.Address,
    due.Month,
    sum(due.Amount - due.Received) AS Due_Amount
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        c.cuid,
        c.name AS name,
        c.address AS address,
        b.month AS Month,
        0 AS Received,
        b.bill_amount AS Amount
    FROM 
        customer c
        INNER JOIN billing b ON c.cuid=b.cuid
    
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        c.cuid,
        c.name AS Name,
        c.address AS Address,
        null AS Month,
        t.received_amount AS Received,
        0 AS Amount
    FROM 
        customer c
        INNER JOIN transaction t ON c.cuid = t.cuid) AS due
GROUP BY 
    due.cuid;
```

**Code generated table is :**

| cuid | Name | Address | Month | Due_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David | City 1 | 1 | 150 |
| 2 | Roja | City 2 | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need all that `SUM()`, `UNION ALL` and subquery. You can do it in a single query and `JOIN` all three tables like this:

```
SELECT c.cuid,
       c.Name,
       c.Address,
       b.Month,
       t.received_amount-b.bill_amount AS Due_Amount
FROM customer c 
  JOIN billing b 
    ON c.cuid=b.cuid
  JOIN transaction t 
    ON c.cuid=t.cuid
    AND b.month=MONTH(t.date);
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce6cac671868715a62faca0be8f0c0d4)

I do have a slight curiosity though because my understanding of `Due_amount` is the remaining amount need to be paid by the customer and yours doesn't seem to be one. If it is, then the value should be negative because the customer `David` paid more (`received_amount`) than the `bill_amount`.

Comment: In trasaction table last row cuid would be 2. Which is edited now.

Comment: The expected result is still the same after the data edit?